# Problems with LibreOffice for Linux since upgrade to 6.0.7

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice

I am having serious problems with LibreOffice since I did the most recent upgrade. Documents that I open (that I have previously saved) will suddenly revert to 'untitled document' or will only save as a template or if I save with a Docx vs a doc extension will save as zip files or will show up as 'text edit' documents in my nextcloud folder and then my client cannot open them on his MacBook.  I was experiencing fairly seamless file conversions from LO for Linux to Windows to Mac prior to this upgrade, but ever since, it's literally been driving me crazy.

I should say that while I am a strong end-user, I am not a programmer. My husband installed Linux on my new ThinkPad because of my disdain for anything Microsoft, and I am running a dual boot w/Windows (thank G*D, because I would have been dead int the water today if I could not have opened files on the windows side).

Is anyone else experiencing issues with LO?

Comment: are the files ok if you save them to your local drive?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Do you still have this issue? or it is already fixed with late releases of LibreOffice?